# What makes you lose the Field Upgrade Score?

Tags: battlefield-4

When playing in a squad, you can get "Field Upgrades". However, sometimes when I die, it tells me that I have lost the "Field Upgrade Score".

**Where can I see this score and what are the events that make me lose it?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I understand it, your Field Upgrade score is measured by your squads effectiveness with working together - attacking an objective works towards this, as well as reviving team-mates, etc. If you die your score drops beneath the level needed for the current Field Upgrade you'll see that message. As for if you can see it, for your actual score, I don't know. For the progress to the next Field Upgrade, it's the bar highlighted below (sorry for small size):

[image]

Comment: Just wanted to add that this is essentially a combination of the field upgrade system featured in Battlefield 2142 as well as the passive bonuses you could slot in Battlefield 3. It has to be unlocked first, which is easiest (earliest) on the support class.

Comment: My bad: you always have the defensive set and unlock the offensive set after varying progress.

Comment: You lose your upgrades if your whole squad dies, not just you. If you keep dying but one person in your squad is still alive you won't lose.

Comment: Yeah, IIRC everyone in your squad loses the upgrades when a Squad Wipe (all of you dead at once) occurs.