# What is the green progress bar in the hub display?

Tags: battlefield-4

There is a green progress bar above the team members names in the BF4 display. I've noticed it displays different icons and changes depending on which class you're playing.

- What is this progress bar for?
- What causes the bar to increase?
- What happens when it hits 100%?
- Does something happen when it reaches on of the icons?
- Is the progress per game or is it persistent the next time I play the game?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That progress bar is for Field Upgrade Score. You can read [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142665/what-affects-field-upgrades-in-bf4) for what causes it to increase. When it hits 100%, you will stop gaining field upgrade score. For reaching the icons, you get different field upgrades depending on your current field upgrade path. The score is only for the current game, and you can [lose it while playing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132883/what-makes-you-lose-the-field-upgrade-score).